# Passing arbitrary amount of paramenters

Tags: python, function

Right now I am trying to do this:

```
def Setup(Param1) :
    repeat(Param1=Param1)

def perform(**kargs) :
    Param1.func()

class Param1 :
    def func(Self) :
        Do_Stuff_To_Self
        return Self
```

I am not sure I properly representing my code, but it's such a large convoluted project that I feel like posting the entire thing would make this worse, but essentially I am working on a wrapper of sorts (perform) that will perform code that is similar between each individual "func" but when I made it and tried building, I am getting the error:

```
global name 'Param1' is not defined.
```

I used the debugger and found that kargs is properly storing 'Param1': "... at instance 0x..." so I am not sure why it is saying Param1 is not defined?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Weilun

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. In the above code, the error appears on line 5.

Comment: Could you post a more complete example such as an [mcve]? I know you purposely tried to shorten down your code to only the problematic area, but we need more context to figure what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arbitrary **named** parameters to a function in Python will store it inside `kwargs` which is a dictionary.

Example:

```
def do_stuff(**kwargs):
  kwargs.get('param1')  # would be 'param1'
  kwargs.get('param2')  # would be 5

do_stuff(param1='param1', param2=5)
```

You can also use **unnamed** parameters where the parameters will be stored as a list

```
def do_stuff2(*args):
  args[0]  # would be 'param1'
  args[1]  # would be 5

do_stuff2('param1', 5)
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much Koralarts!